# Setting value for specific ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've made a component that copies some code from a code box. The component javascript looks like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'code',
  classNames: ['lm-code-box'],
  dataTarget: null,
  dataTrigger: Ember.computed('dataTarget',
    function() {
      return `.${this.get('dataTarget')}`;
    }
  ),
  copyAction: null,
  icon: 'ion-code',
  copyStatus: null,
  buttonText: 'Copy',
  didInsertElement() {
    this.clipboard = new Clipboard('.lm-button--copy');

    this.clipboard.on('success',(e) => {
      this.set('icon','ion-checkmark');
      this.set('copyStatus','success');
      this.set('buttonText','Copied');
      e.clearSelection();
    });

    this.clipboard.on('error',(e) => {
      this.set('icon','ion-android-warning');
      this.set('copyStatus','error');
      this.set('buttonText','Error');
    });
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    this.clipboard.destroy();
  }
});
```

Component code looks like:

```
<a class="lm-button--copy {{buttonClass}}" data-clipboard-target={{dataTrigger}} data-clipboard-action={{copyAction}}>
  {{buttonText}} 
  <i class="icon {{icon}}"></i>
</a>
<pre class="{{dataTarget}}">
  {{yield}}
</pre>
```

Then in my template the code looks like:

```
{{#lm-code-copy dataTarget="testOne"
                        copyAction="copy"}}
    test one
{{/lm-code-copy}}
{{#lm-code-copy dataTarget="testTwo"
                        copyAction="copy"}}
    test two
{{/lm-code-copy}}
```

Everything copies fine, but in the block:

```
this.set('icon','ion-checkmark');
this.set('copyStatus','success');
this.set('buttonText','Copied');
```

changes those key values on both components that are rendered. How can I tell ember to only change the value for the current component? I assumed `this` would set that context but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pedro Rio was close. Using [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/) you have to pass in a DOM element similar to jquery using syntanx like `clipboard = new Clipboard('.class-name')` or `clipboard = new Clipboard('#id-name')`. Somehow, in Ember world the scope of `this` was bound to the scope of Clipboard.js's query. So the fix was to use Ember's jQuery syntax to scope clipboard to each button item.

```
this.clipboard = new Clipboard(this.$(`.lm-button--copy`).get(0));
```

Please note that there is no `.` after `this.$` as there is in the other answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the `this.$.` it was a typo. And thanks for pointing it out. Don't wan't to trip other readers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a chance here, since you didn't supply your component template. I think you're problem might be with your CSS selector

```
this.clipboard = new Clipboard('.lm-button--copy');
```

You're always targeting all `.lm-button--copy` elements in the page with that selector. Meaning that each component instance will have a separate `this.clipboard` reference but all pointing to the same dom element.

Also the `this` you refer to is not the component:

```
this.clipboard.on('success',(e) => { <--- This `this` is your component
  this.set('icon','ion-checkmark'); 
  this.set('copyStatus','success'); <---- These `this` are the context of the invoking success handler (you can set a break point here to see its not the ember component)
  this.set('buttonText','Copied');
  e.clearSelection();
});
```

You might want something like this (assuming this `Clipboard` thing can also receive a dom element):

```
this.clipboard = new Clipboard(this.$('.lm-button--copy'));
```

In an Ember component `this.$` refers to the outer div that wraps the component. As such you will only select elements that are within the component. Which I think what you might need.

Comment: I update my code to show the missing component, thanks for bringing that to my attention. As for `this.clipboard = new Clipboard('.lm-button--copy');` - that is clipboard.js own syntax, it is not jQuery. Just fyi.